# Inline Object Comparison Java

Tags: java, sorting, comparator

I am trying to sort an arraylist with the following method. I want US to be first, followed by UK, etc. However this doesn't seem to be doing anything. What am I doing wrong?

```
    orderedTerritories.sort((o1, o2) -> {
        if (o1.getCode().equals("US*"))
            return 1;
        else if (o2.getCode().equals("US*"))
            return 0;
        else if (o1.getCode().contains("UK") && o1.getContains() != null)
            return 1;
        else if (o2.getCode().contains("UK") && o2.getContains() != null)
            return 0;
        else if (o1.getCode().equals("DE*"))
            return 1;
        else if (o2.getCode().equals("DE*"))
            return 0;
        else if (o1.getCode().equals("JP"))
            return 1;
        else if (o2.getCode().equals("JP"))
            return 0;
        else if (o1.getCode().equals("IN"))
            return 1;
        else if (o2.getCode().equals("IN"))
            return 0;
        else return 1;
    });
```

Comment: Well, the first thing that strikes me is none of the elements are considered to be less than any other (indicated by returning -1). That might be messing with the algorithm.

Comment: To me, a way more logical way of achieving this is translate every country code to a number, sort based on number order, then translate back into country codes.

Comment: The thing that strikes me about this is that your description doesn't even match the tests.  You say "US" first followed by "UK" and so on, but you are testing for "US*", codes that *contain* "UK" and so on.

Comment: If i see US i want it first, then return.. else if I see UK I want it first if its not being compared to US, etc

Comment: `String` and numbers are not models of a country identifier. Neither offers an object-oriented approach. How about capturing the nationality in an `enum`? Then you get ordering for free, and it's type safe, and you can't fudge up the spelling or the mapping, and your comparisons and logic get both easier and faster.

Comment: Can't since I cant hard code it in. Is there no way to do simple ordering in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your sorting logic dose not check if both code's are same and also returns 0 instead of negative value when o1.getCode() is less than o2.getCode() . Without doing it you are breaking comparator contract.

Based on your sorting logic you can't simply rely on country code's string representation for sorting. To mitigate it you need to define a custom ordering value to each country. I am assuming that you can't modify the get code method to return Enum or some custom object. In that case you can define a map between country code and order and use that order value for sorting. Here is an example:

One of comments already is suggesting similar approach.

```
     private static Map<String, Interger> codeToOrderMap = new HashMap<>();

    static{
     codeToOrderMap.put("US*", 0);
     codeToOrderMap.put("UK", 1);
     codeToOrderMap.put("DE*", 2);
     codeToOrderMap.put("JP", 3);
     codeToOrderMap.put("IN", 4);
    }

    orderedTerritories.sort((o1, o2) ->
codeToOrderMap.get( o1.getCode() ).compareTo( codeToOrderMap.get( o2.getCode() );
```

Without using above approach or custom code you will have to write a very long messy comparator.

Comment: This was basically what I was suggesting. 10 minutes before bed though isn't when I wanted to start writing an answer though. Gotta love maps.

Comment: I did mention it in my answer and upvoted your answer.

Comment: Ya, I wasn't hating on this answer. I +1'd it. I've gotten flak before for posting pseudoanswers in the comments, so I just wanted to point out that this is what I was going for.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to agree with Lew Bloch in that you should use a more object oriented approach by using an enum.

I don't understand your response to the comment that Lew Bloch posted. You said, "Can't since I cant hard code it in. Is there no way to do simple ordering in java?" but you're already hardcoding the values in your current code. For example you have things like this in your code:

`o1.getCode().equals("US*")` In this statement the "US*" is hardcoded.

Here is an example of the enum approach using just US and UK codes:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Example implements Comparable<Example>
{
  public enum CountryCode{
    US,UK
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    List<Example> codeList = new ArrayList<>();
    codeList.add(new Example(CountryCode.UK));
    codeList.add(new Example(CountryCode.US));

    System.out.println("Before sort: "+codeList);
    Collections.sort(codeList);
    System.out.println("After sort: "+codeList);

  }

  private CountryCode countryCode;

  public Example(CountryCode code){
    this.countryCode = code;
  }

  public CountryCode getCountryCode(){
    return countryCode;
  }

  public int compareTo(Example other){
    return this.countryCode.compareTo(other.getCountryCode());
  }

  public String toString(){
    return "Example: "+countryCode.toString();
  }
}
```

Since the enum contains US and UK in that order and the `Example` class defers to the enum for its implementation of `compareTo` the `List` of `Example` is sorted such that `Example` objects whose country code is US come before those with a country code of UK.

**OUTPUT**:

```
Before sort: [Example: UK, Example: US]
After sort: [Example: US, Example: UK]
```

**Final Items**: I'm not clear what the "*" is meant to represent in your code values. If there are requirements that you have not specified then this approach may not work as intended.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, I factored in what you guys said to the following solution, which works:

```
       List<Territory> orderedTerritories = new LinkedList<>();
       List<Integer> integerValues = new ArrayList<>();
       Map<Integer, Territory> intToTerritoryMap = new HashMap<>();
       int i = 5;
       for (Territory territory : finalSet) {
            int index = 5;
            if (territory.getCode().equals("US*"))
                index = 0;
            else if (territory.getCode().contains("UK") && territory.getContains() != null)
                index = 1;
            else if (territory.getCode().equals("DE*"))
                index = 2;
            else if (territory.getCode().equals("JP"))
                index = 3;
            else if (territory.getCode().equals("IN"))
                index = 4;
            if (index < 5) {
                intToTerritoryMap.put(index, territory);
                integerValues.add(index);
            } else {
                intToTerritoryMap.put(i, territory);
                integerValues.add(i++);
            }
        }
        Collections.sort(integerValues);

        integerValues.forEach(j -> {
            orderedTerritories.add(intToTerritoryMap.get(j));
        });

        return orderedTerritories;
```

Which is verbose and hard codes in numbers. I wish there was a simpler way.

Comment: Now that the code works, you can post it on Code Review to get it reviewed. Note though that they require full, complete, runnable code.